# Catching exception from Fortran dll in C#

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, exception, fortran

We have a WPF PRISM application with an unhandled exception handler which catches unhandled exceptions and gives the user a friendly message.

The application uses a C# wrapper class library which in turn uses a fortran dll.
Errors (occasional) thrown by the fortran dll do not seem to be caught by the exception handler.

How can I catch these exceptions?

UPDATE:
Irrespective of the kind of exceptions thrown by the fortran dll, I just want to catch them all in my C# WPF PRISM application. Why does the UnhandledExceptionEventHandler from System.Runtime.InteropServices not catch the fortran exception?

Comment: What kind of exceptions are involved? Is the fortran dll running managed or unmanaged/native code?

Comment: Fortran (normally) doesn't have any exceptions (except IEEE FPE). What you are trying to catch?

Comment: I say again Fortran doesn't have ANY exceptions. What is the thing you want to catch? The STOP statement?

Comment: Are the Fortran routines just returning error codes that you want to throw as exceptions if they are not, say zero.  If so, do that in your wrapper because, as Vladmir says, Fortran does not have exceptions.